# Original paper for DisparityWLSFilter in openCV?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, filtering, opencv3.0, disparity-mapping

I am working on post processing of disparity map.
My disparity image, even though it is WLS filtered, has too many 'holes'.

[image: Raw disparity, unfiltered]
[image: WLS filtered]
This is what i get for now. Rectified, but in fish eye way. Anyway rectified for sure, but have many holes. Disparity matching algorithm is SGBM. WLS filter sigma is 2.1, lambda is 30000. Black regions are holes.

I am referring official opencv site which says [Disparity map post-filtering](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d14/tutorial_ximgproc_disparity_filtering.html#gsc.tab=0) and it is using **DisparityWLSFilter** extensively. But I wonder how it works internally and want to read theoretical **paper regarding this implementation**. I want to know what Sigma and Lambda does, and how it will filter my image.

And, is there any other good disparity filter that i can use? WLS filter cannot fill the 'holes' effectively. Or, any algorithm that is easy to use or easy to implement, or library that is not GPL?

Answer (score 2):

Self reply.
Got answer from Opencv.

Orig question is [HERE](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/issues/587#issuecomment-197861312).

Reply says

> References have been added [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/commit/7c421ba2b39b8869a7b89cabdd167a3eb5e55963#diff-52ae9091791bac0bb959b7554ee3a53b), [documentation reference](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d13/classcv_1_1ximgproc_1_1FastGlobalSmootherFilter.html#details&gsc.tab=0)
>   cc @sbokov
>   —
>   You are receiving this because you authored the thread.
>   Reply to this email directly or view it on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

Check out the comments [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/2de6ff576c75ab96e10f5b38dfcfeae013471b63/modules/ximgproc/include/opencv2/ximgproc/disparity_filter.hpp#L78), and the code [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/2de6ff576c75ab96e10f5b38dfcfeae013471b63/modules/ximgproc/src/disparity_filters.cpp#L49). That should answer some of your questions. To see how the code author has come up with this method perhaps should contact him directly as there is no reference for that in the code comments.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I doubt that i could get any answer from the sole author.. anyway request was sent. Better try than nothing. Thanks for reminding me that. What i found so far is This [Link](http://publish.illinois.edu/visual-modeling-and-analytics/files/2014/10/FGS-TIP.pdf) and another [Link](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/1370000/1360666/a67-farbman.pdf?ip=163.152.126.27&id=1360666&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=0EC22F8658578FE1%2E92929792C8912683%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35&CFID=762570584&CFTOKEN=54500157&__acm__=1458205715_ad4c6c63ac85f08dc1f5e2dfadae18c6) but not sure also